# mysql query with and safe from injections?

Tags: mysql

Good day to you all, sorry for asking such a primitive question... but i can't answer it!
We have to input fields:
login
password

And a resulting mysql

> SELECT user.Ident, user.fname, user.lname FROM t_users as user WHERE user.login= :login and  user.pass=:password and user.status=0

I'm not a hacker, 've never used mysql injections myself... so i can't say that it's safe... because setting login to "' OR 1; #" won't work.

**EDIT 1**

if i input
login = "' OR 1; #"
password = '52352352'
i get this

```
 Error Number: 1064
```

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' and user.pass='a32d2f2e60c1757c53cfbc3086d9ecc1' and user.status=0' at line 8`

**EDIT 2**
Question closed, thanks for your answers!

Comment: try to print the values of variable before you use them in query. is `status` string field?

Comment: is your password encrypted in that case ur select should be like `select * from tableName where login='login' and password = md5('password')`

Comment: @Elmor Question closed? No. Only if you accept an answer, and even then it'll be possible to answer further.

Comment: I've ticked up manurajhada answer/ i thought that that's all

Answer (score 2):

remove double equal to (==) from `user.login= = :login`.
Sql compare with single equals (=).

**Edit:**
Try it..

```
SELECT user.Ident, user.fname, user.lname FROM t_users as user 
WHERE user.login=:login and user.pass=:password and user.status='0';
```

Comment: I didn't specify it at once, but :login & :password are the places where input from appropriate fields is placed.